# How to sum a data cube with python

Tags: python, sum, cube, fits

I am trying to collapse a fits data cube with Python. I know that special packages are doing it, but it is for a lecture purposes. I first extract a subcube in Z:
**`hdu.data = hdu.data[3365:3405, :, :]`
`subcube = hdu.data`**
The subcube has a dimension of Z=40, Y=50 and X=26. I want to collapse the cube in a all fashion way by a double loop in X and Y, in order to have a simple 2D image.

```
for i in range(1, xdim):
    for j in range(1, ydim):    
        Sum[j,i] = subcube[:,j,i].sum()
```

I get an error message: IndexError: index 26 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 26.
I know that python handle differently the cube dimensions as Z, Y, X and not X, Y, Z like IDL for example, but I can not figure out why I have the error.

Answer (score 1):

Python ranges starts with 0. Range for X is 0-25. For Y and Z the same.
Maybe simple double loop over subcube with new list creation can hel you?
`z_flatten = [[sum(col) for col in row] for row in subcube]`

Answer (score 1):

Python indices start at 0. You need to do `range(xdim)` and `range(ydim)` in your for loops.

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for your help. I had tried the loop beginning at 0 in one version, without success. But looking more closely I realised that I hadn't  "declared" the array correctly: Sum = np.zeros([xdim,ydim]), instead of Sum = np.zeros([ydim,xdim]) !! Stupid mistakes .... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers pointing out that Python is 0-indexed are correct, but no one pointed out yet that you don't even need to create an empty array with `np.zeros` or to use any `for` loops to do this.

Numpy already allows you to apply most operations along a specific *axis* of your array, as opposed to looping over the dimensions of your sub-cube and summing just one pixel at a time.

For example let's make a 3x4x4 data cube:

```py
>>> cube = np.arange(3 * 4 * 4).reshape((3, 4, 4))
>>> cube
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26, 27],
        [28, 29, 30, 31]],

       [[32, 33, 34, 35],
        [36, 37, 38, 39],
        [40, 41, 42, 43],
        [44, 45, 46, 47]]])
```

Say you want to sum all layers of a 3x3 slice of this cube:

```py
>>> cube[:, :3, :3].sum(axis=0)
array([[48, 51, 54],
       [60, 63, 66],
       [72, 75, 78]])
```

In your case, the equivalent would be

```py
subcube[:, :ydim, :xdim].sum(axis=0)
```

This is equivalent to what you're trying to do, but much more efficient.

As a general note, although you read your data cube out of a FITS file, since `astropy.io.fits` returns a Numpy array, any documentation or questions you can find about Numpy arrays apply--it generally isn't important at that point that it came from a FITS file.  I point this out, just because it might help you in the future if you're struggling to perform operations on Numpy arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate. H